# How to randomize an array of a String so it is different every time though the loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I am making a description generator and am splitting a text file at a ":". So if the text file had "dog:fish:cat:bird", my code splits it at the ":" and randomly picks one. However, when I print out my ending results, the output is all the same. It will randomly pick the words in the array but then if I said generate it 4 times, it would be the same thing 4 times. So where is my logic wrong on how to approach this? I want it to print 4 random different things. My code is below:

public class Generator 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();

    System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
    String fName = scanner.nextLine();
    File infle = new File(fName);
    Scanner read = new Scanner(infle);

    System.out.print("Enter number to make: ");
    int things = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Here are " + things + " things: ");
    System.out.println();


    //gets random animal
    String animal = read.nextLine();
    String[]anm1 = animal.split(":");
    int rnd_Animal = r.nextInt(anm1.length);
    String rndAnimal = (anm1[rnd_Animal]);


    //gets random adjective
    String adj = read.next();
    String []adj1 = adj.split(":");
    int rndAdj = r.nextInt(adj1.length);
    String randomAdj = (adj1[rndAdj]);


    for(int i=0; i <things; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(randomAdj + " " + rndAnimal);}
```

So, my output would print like: "sweaty fish" as many times as I entered for it to be generated. How can I get it to say "sweaty fish","smelly dog","slow fish" if I entered 3 descriptions to be generated? Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think you need to put the "gets random animal" and "gets random adjective" code block inside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you get the value for **rndAnimal** and **randomAdj** outside the for loop. So it gets the value randomly **ONLY ONCE** and displays it four times. To solve the problem, assign the value to the two Strings inside the loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<things; i++){

    //gets random animal 
    String animal = read.nextLine();
    String[]anm1 = animal.split(":"); 
    int rnd_Animal =r.nextInt(anm1.length); 
    String rndAnimal =(anm1[rnd_Animal]); 

    //gets random adjective 
    String adj = read.next(); 
    String []adj1 = adj.split(":"); 
    int rndAdj = r.nextInt(adj1.length);
    String randomAdj = (adj1[rndAdj]);

    System.out.println(randomAdj + " " + rndAnimal);
}
```

Comment: that is definitely it. However, I have a couple other random objects in there and I get a "no line found error". the order of my random objects go, nextLine, next,nextLine,nextLine,nextLine,nextLine. I have the one next in there because it takes from that array twice and I keep fliiping the nexLine and next around but can not seem to get it. Any idea even though that sounds confusing?

Comment: To solve that, I'd suggest you to take care of the scope of objects first, and then check the text file. You might have a problem with file I/O, and you could look for a solution to that, but the problem you ask help for in the question is already solved. See if it helps.

Comment: After further examining your code, If I put everything in the for loop, it will take words from other lines which is not what I need it to do. It has to take the random words in text file from just that line only and that is why I am getting a line not found error.

Comment: Or you can also do one thing, take the input from whichever line you want and store it in a string var. Now forget the file. Use the string as your source. This would make it simple. Generate the random strings inside the loop using the main string outside the loop.

Comment: all I had to do was put my final random string inside the loop and leave everything else on the outside and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for all of your help.